# What should I config to delete path?

Tags: doxygen

What should I do to delete this path or set like relative, like src only?

[image: Picture]

Comment: The description is not very clear to me what you want, so please clarify!. But I think the options that come in question here are `FULL_PATH_NAMES`, `TRIP_FROM_PATH` and `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` (see documentation chapter "Configuration")

Comment: I dont want to have there the path- C:Users\skola\... I want to disable it, I solve this for file list with FULL_PATH_NAMES, but there is still path. Thanks

Comment: Please specify the doxygen version used and also the differences in your Doxyfile compared to the standard Doxyfile (when using the latest release, 1.8.15, you can get these differences by means of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and edit the results into the question.